# Is it normal to use many business exceptions if needed?

Tags: c#, architecture, exception

Is it a good practice to define and throw custom exceptions even if the application needs lots of them?

- EntityNotFoundException
- EntityAlreadyExistsException
- EntityNotUniqueException
- EntityNotAddedException
- EntityNotUpdatedException
- EntityNotDeletedException
- QuizOverException
- QuizExpiredException
- TableAlreadyBookedException
- EndDateMustBeGreaterThanStartDateException

I tried to name these sample exception names to describe their purpose as good as I could. I hope they could form an idea of what I am trying to ask.

Don't limit your imagination with only these exceptions but all that could arise during you application's life. Consider both CRUD and business exceptions.

I know that throwing and catching exceptions is an expensive process in terms of performance but don't they provide a more elegant way to develop you app?

- Isn't it better to throw a `EntityNotFoundException` instead of writing an if statement to check whether the entity is null?
- Isn't it better to throw a `EntityAlreadyExistsException` instead of writing an additional if statement which will call a method to check whether the entity with the given Id already exists?
- Isn't it better to throw a `EntityNotAddedException` instead of checking the return value of type bool specifying whether the transaction was successful or not? What if we want to return an object?

I feel that the answer will be like "you should not use `EntityNotFoundException` but instead check if null, but you should use `EntityAlreadyExistsException`", "there is no holy grail".

I am wondering what is the elegant way of doing this?

Comment: If the application needs lots of custom exceptions, then it is good practice to define and throw lots of custom exceptions, simply because it's the only way. If there were another way than to define and throw lots of custom exceptions, the application does not need lots of custom exceptions.

Comment: If you are planning to throw multiple exceptions then, I am assuming, you must be planning to catch them all in multiple catch blocks as well. Whatever your decision on your question is, IMO at the end put a generic catch(Exception ex) kind of block as well so that you do not miss out on catching any exception which you might not have thought of. Of course code that part carefully and gracefully.

Comment: @samar "*IMO at the end put a generic `catch (Exception ex)` kind of block as well*" - not good advice. The point is you only catch the exceptions which you *know* you can handle, everything else should bubble up and kill the application because it's now *technically* in a corrupt state.

Comment: @James; That is why I told to handle that part carefully like logging it in database or something and showing a custom error to user instead of getting a dirty exception screen or the window closing down abruptly. But yeah your point is also valid in a way. Thanks.

Comment: @samar James makes a good point, there's no point catching an exception if there's nothing you can do about it. Catching **all** exceptions and logging them to a database doesn't make sense - what if it's an exception indicating that the database server wasn't found? Now you have 2 exceptions... what if you're logging the exception to a file, and the exception was that the application didn't have permission to write to the log file? What if it's an `OutOfMemoryException` and you have no chance of doing anything useful? I cannot think of *any* good reason for `catch (Exception)` anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keeping in mind that exceptions are supposed to represent *exceptional* circumstances all of your questions can only really be answered with - **it depends**.

The context of when & where you intend on throwing a particular exception will naturally decide whether it makes sense. For example, if you attempt to retrieve an entity that *should* exist but doesn't, then throwing an `EntityNotFoundException` would be considered appropriate because we now have an *exceptional* circumstance. On the other hand, if you are checking whether the entity already exists before creating a new one then you could argue that because we know there is a chance the entity may or may not exist then it's not really an exceptional circumstance.

Like I said, it really depends on the context of the situation and the nature of your application whether you should throw an exception or not, however, the one thing you don't want to end up doing is controlling the program flow with exceptions.

To help make the distinction between when it's suitable to use an exception vs business logic, simply ask yourself "*is this particular situation valid?*" or in other words "*is it OK for the application to find itself in this state?*". If the answer is yes, use logic to control the flow of the application and deal with the situation, otherwise you want to throw an `Exception` to effectively interrupt the program flow and inform the user that something isn't quite right.

Comment: So roughly speaking, your answer is "it depends" and fair enough, it is the way to go. I like the idea that, for instance in case of an entity not being found, you should sometimes throw an exception OR check if null depending on the situation rather than doing the same thing every time this case occurs. But what if I want to check the result of a transaction by looking at the return value (an integer statusCode or a boolean value) of the method AND at the same time I want to return an object from the same method. How should one control the flow?

Comment: @Anar yes for your particular question it is because you don't give any specific examples on how you intend to throw the exceptions. Well for that scenario you could use an `out` parameter to return the status code, however, I would question why you also would need to inspect the status code - the result would determine whether the call was successful (if it returns `null` then you know the entity doesn't exist). If you know the entity *may* not exist then you shouldn't be throwing an exception because it's *expected* behaviour. If the entity *must* exist but doesn't, then that's different.

Answer (score 2):

When creating exceptions ask about their added value. 
Will someone care about specific types of exception to be caught? 
Will exceptions have different fields to help exception handling? 
More abstract exception with custom message can save you time writing exceptions with no value.

Using exceptions to control program flow is considered bad idea. Here are some reasons:

- Exceptions have been created for concept of error handling
- Performance as you said
- you can forget to handle some exceptions
- If you use checked exceptions you may need to write handlers for exceptions you do not care about or don't know how to handle.
- Exceptions increase uncertainty in programs (exceptions thrown while exception handling, finally statements,...)

There are other ways to solve conditional statements, take a look at scala programming language and its use of "monads".

Comment: I didn't explicitly ask about controlling the flow using exceptions, but your points are valid.

Comment: @Anar you did not, but many of the exceptions you mentioned in your question are *very* likely to be used for controlling program flow. So you kind of implicitly did ask.

Comment: Now that I read your comment I must say you are right, I kind of implicitly asked.

Answer (score 2):

One major limitation with the exception-handling paradigm in C++, which was inherited by Java and subsequently .NET, is that if a call to `Foo` throws a `BozException`, that can have two very different meanings:

- Some condition was detected during the execution of `Foo` which implied that it should throw a `BozException`.
- Foo called some method which it was not expecting to throw a `BozException`, but the method threw one anyway and `Foo` didn't catch it,  the exception was thrown out of `Foo`.

Even though the Framework guidelines discourage the use of custom exceptions when an existing exception would seem to "fit", the lack of any standard means for code that catches a Framework-defined exception to know whether it actually represents an expected circumstance is a pretty big disadvantage to using a Framework exception (like `InvalidOperationException`) to report business-logic circumstances a caller might want to handle (e.g. trying to add to a `Dictionary` to records with the same ID).  If you can tolerate the boilerplate associated with defining exceptions, I'd suggest that it's better to err on the side of too many rather than too few (though you may wish to use inheritance for exceptions that will likely be handled the same way).

Answer (score 1):

As with almost everything in software development, given a general rule or best practise the skill is knowing when and how to apply it.

Should I program to an interface?  YES!  Should I make every single class I write implement a corresponding interface and only ever program to that abstraction?  I could do but writing a  very simple application would take me an age and my productivity would grind to a halt.

Single Responsibility - is it a good thing?  YES!  Does every class I write have exactly one and only one responsibility.  No - partly because of my own failings as a programmer, but also because I'd end up with a plethora of single-method classes and an unmanageably disconnected code base.

Now let us turn to error handling:

Firstly, by looking at your comment to [James'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17970307/2382536) answer, let us clarify that using [error codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_code) and [exception handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling) represent two distinct models of handling errors in your application and as a general rule they should not be mixed.

Let us assume you are using exception handling and make the following argument:

**Why do we throw exceptions?**

We throw an exception because *something bad has happened*.  If we are expecting a scenario to occur some point, then it is within the flow of our application, and is therefore not exceptional - so throwing an `Exception` would not be appropriate!

With this argument, it makes little sense to throw anything other than the top level `Exception` class, as any other exception implies that we have foreseen this scenario and have been able to attach extra metadata to the exception.

**Why handle exception?**

Having thrown an exception, we expect someone somewhere to deal with it, hopefully with the intention of restoring the application to a consistent state.  However, if the exception is truly exceptional - we can have no way of knowing what state has been corrupted so exception handling is futile.

**Isn't this taking things a bit too far?**

Well - this is exactly how error handling works in a service orientated architecture. A robust service should not reveal any incriminating details of what has happened when an exception occurs (it's a security breach and introduces coupling between the service and the client) - all the client needs to know is *something bad happened*.

However, I'm guessing that we are working within an Object Orientated environment, where we are prepared to accept a slightly higher degree of coupling between an implementation and it's consumers.  And it is this that is the important point - *by introducing an exception hierarchy which exposes detailed information about the exception you increase the coupling in your application* (the consumers need to have detailed knowledge about all the exceptions you could throw).

In software we strive for a loosely coupled code base, making it easy to maintain and extend.  I have no doubt there is a happy medium between the SOA approach to exceptions and the one you describe in your question - finding that sweet spot is the skill of the developer.

Comment: Exception handling does a very good job of handling the scenario where a method's *immediate* calling code is not prepared to handle a condition that occurs within a method, but the surrounding code (often in the same method as the call site) is prepared for the possibility that the condition may have occurred at any of the call sites within it. For example, a method that reads ten pieces of data from a file might have code to handle the possibility that a read may fail (without caring which one), but the individual read operations may not have such code.

Comment: I actually think there should be fewer types of exceptions, rather than more, but that should be balanced by having exceptions contain more information besides the low-level kind of thing that went wrong. The distinctions between `ArgumentException` and `InvalidOperationException` are far less useful than would be distinctions between `CleanFailureException`,  `ValidPartialOperationException`, `ObjectCorruptedException`, and `CpuOnFireException`.

Comment: I like the rule that library code should throw exceptions, and application code should catch them.  That places the onus of handling exceptions (which may differ in various scenarios) on the more volatile application code.  I am interested as to how any code could appropriately respond to a `CpuOnFireException` though..!

Comment: `CpuOnFireException` was an example of one code *shouldn't* try to handle `>:*3`. I don't see a basis for limiting exception handling to the application layer, since it will have no way of knowing whether an `InvalidOperationException` that occurs during `LoadDocument` indicates any problem beyond the fact that the document couldn't load. If I were designing a language/framework, I'd include a virtual properties in `Exception` for `bool ShouldCatch<T>(ref T param)` and `IsResolved`; that would allow for smooth handling of cases where one exception causes another.

Comment: If one exception causes more, exception-related actions should be triggered if they are applicable to *any* of those exceptions, but only after *all* exceptions are "satisfied" should they stop propagating up the call stack.  Unfortunately, the present design of `catch` assumes that once an exception is caught that should end all exception handling unless an exception is thrown or rethrown while processing the `catch`.